# Carbon Credit Prices

Tags: finance, prices

I am looking for Carbon Credit Prices, for different geographical zones. Ideally I'd like a reference data source with a practical API. Any idea on where to get that ?

Comment: Show us the URLs of datasources you've googled already, and explain **why** each one was unsuitable for your use case. How may we revise the question so it is more focused on what you seek?